# Printing only the first returned value to the view in Angular2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript2.0, string-interpolation

In my Angular 2 app I am using string interpolation to print to the view some data. I am using an `*ngFor` to iterate over an array of objects, looking for a certain value in each of those objects, and if found, printing that value to the screen. This is working as expected.

However, on occasion, more than one value is returned - when more than one of the three objects checked has a value for that particular property. This throws off the layout. In these instances I'm wondering if there's a way I can add some logic (to the view specifically) so that ONLY the first value found gets printed.

This is what I have:

```
        <ng-container *ngFor="let status of record.status">
            <td *ngIf="status?.level === currentLevel &&
                        status?.step">
                {{status?.step}}
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="status?.level !== currentLevel ||
                        !status?.step">
                {{'N/A'}}
            </td>
        </ng-container>
```

Is there something I can add to this view code to accomplish handling this logic?

Comment: Why are you doing this in the template? Do it in the class instead.

Comment: what does when more than one of the three objects checked has a value for that particular property means

Comment: Jon, when someone asks a question, rather than telling them how they should do it, perhaps stick to the question at hand. I realize this is usually done in the component, but in this particular case (this one time), I want to handle it in the template, if possible. And according to the answer below, it looks like this is possible.

Comment: `let status of record.status; #first=first` instead of `let status of record.status, #first=first`

Comment: Right. I caught that and made the change to the semi-colon -- still erroring out with the same error, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the first element as below

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let status of status;  #first=first">
```

And the use it as you want.

#### Result :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let status of record.status; #first = first">
      <div *ngIf="first">
         <td *ngIf="status?.level === currentLevel && status?.step">
                        {{status?.step}}
          </td>
          <td *ngIf="status?.level !== currentLevel || !status?.step">
                        {{'N/A'}}
          </td>
      </div>

    </ng-container>
```

#### OR for ng2

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let status of record.status;  let i = index">
      <div *ngIf="i ===0">
         <td *ngIf="status?.level === currentLevel && status?.step">
                        {{status?.step}}
          </td>
          <td *ngIf="status?.level !== currentLevel || !status?.step">
                        {{'N/A'}}
          </td>
      </div>

    </ng-container>
```

Comment: Do I need to reference #first elsewhere as well? Right now this is causing a compilation error for me.

Comment: You don't have to reference it.  Try changing it to <ng-container *ngFor="let status of status,  let first=first"> or would you please give us the thrown error ?

Comment: Parser Error: Unexpected token #, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 46 in [let status of record.status, #first=first] in DisplayComponent@83:28 ("g-container *ngFor="let status of record.status, #first=first">

Comment: You declaration is okay. Which angular version are you using. Note that `first` is a boolean. So the content of your ng-container must be wrapped inside it.

Please use ; instead of  ,

Comment: After matching to what you have above, I'm still getting the error. Is this syntax perhaps something that only works in Angular4 on?

Comment: Maybe it's a version problem. Check with index. I edited my answer.